# Zebra ZPL II Code to scale QR-Codes (^BQ)

Tags: qr-code, barcode, zebra-printers

I would like to print bigger QR-Codes to increase the scannable range. The magnification factor is already set to 10.

```
^XA
^FWN
^LH0,0
^FO50,40^A0R,75,75^FDTEST^FS
^FO150,45
^BQR,2,10,H,7^FDQA,TEST^FS
^PQ1
^XZ
```

[ZPL result preview](http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=8&width=4&height=4&units=inches&index=0&zpl=%5EXA%0A%5EFWN%0A%5ELH0%2C0%0A%5EFO50%2C40%5EA0R%2C75%2C75%5EFDTEST%5EFS%0A%5EFO150%2C45%0A%5EBQR%2C2%2C10%2CH%2C7%5EFDQA%2CTEST%5EFS%0A%5EPQ1%0A%5EXZ)

Is there a way to scale the QR-Code, i would like to scale up the QR-Code  by faktor 1.5

[ZPL II Guide](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `^JMB` to change the dots per millimeter.  It will double the size, then you'll have to tweak it in `^BQ` to get it where you want it.  Also, I'm not sure `^BQR` does anything, it looks like it only accepts `^BQN` as a valid orientation.